# Simple peak detection in python: issues with both find_peaks_cwt and peakutils

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, peakutils

This is an example similar to what my data looks like, there's a sharp peak, surrounded by some small noise, and mostly constant elsewhere with small noise.

Both `find_peaks_cwt` and `peakutils` don't perform as I would have hoped on this data.

[image]

`find_peaks_cwt`:

```
>>> x
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2, 0.0, 0.005, 0.1, 0.1]
>>> peaks = scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange(1,5))
>>> peaks
[1, 2, 3, 9, 12, 16, 17]
```

16 and 17 were correct peaks, but what's up with 1,2,3,9,12 being detected? Also, this routine lacks the ability to identify 16/17 as a single peak. That's somewhat problematic for me.

The `findpeaks` package seems more robust, and I've tried implementing it, but it has weird issues. It will throw exceptions for no reason that makes sense to me when I look at the data (there's a clear peak), and sometimes it'll even produce negative indexes for no obvious reason! I got the buggy heeby jeebies after working with it for a while.

Even on this example, `peakutils` doesn't seem to perform as hoped for:

```
>>> x
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2, 0.0, 0.005, 0.1, 0.1]
>>> peakutils.indexes(x, thres=0.0) # I tried many values of thres
array([], dtype=int64)
```

Any suggestions on identifying sharp peaks like this? I'm considering not using peak detection and just writing my own function to identify them.

Comment: Performance of find_peaks_cwt depends on the wavelet widths you provide, e.g. try giving it some other than arange(1,5) eg linspace(1,5,100) --- you'll probably need to read the paper it's based on in order to use it properly.

Comment: I understand, and yes, I just tried `arange(1,100)`, and it picked up the peak correctly in this test example. I'll experiment with this more and look at the paper. You should post that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand the algorithm myself --- it seems not always return the exact maximum index if the peak has a relatively flat top. Not sure if a bug, or whether this was intended behavior as a "best" estimate of peak center position.

Comment: I've now been through a lot of peak detection libraries, they all seem to have quirks, and getting really consistent results is not easy. Sharp peaks in particular are problematic, in this case I ended up doing a simple heuristic identifying the largest value and zeroing out data nearby. It works because the peak is so pronounced. I've used `findpeaks` in another case where the data is noisy and get ok results, but not what I would call truly consistent.